# How to reduce a custom bin histogram for a region in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, histogram

I'd like to reduce all the conties' data histogram with a custom bin, but what I got is a auto bin histogram, it seems ee.Reducer.fixedHistogram() can help, but I don't know how to pass the parameters(min,max,steps) for all conties.

> // load precip data (mm, daily total): 365 images per year

```
var precipCollection = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET')
                    .select('pr')   // select  precip band only
                    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');
print(precipCollection, 'precipCollection');
```

> ```
> // load precip data (mm, daily total): 365 images per year
> ```

```
var precipCollection = ee.ImageCollection('IDAHO_EPSCOR/GRIDMET')
                    .select('pr')   // select  precip band only
                    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31');
print(precipCollection);
```

> // reduce the image collection to one image by summing the 365 daily
>   rasters

```
var annualPrecip = precipCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
print(annualPrecip);
```

> ```
> // equivalent shortcut syntax
> ```

```
var annualPrecip2 = precipCollection.sum();

// visualize annual precipitation
var precipPal = ['white','blue'] // store palette as variable               
Map.addLayer(annualPrecip, {min: 60, max: 3000, palette: precipPal}, 'precip');
```

> // load regions: counties from a public fusion table, removing
>   non-conus states
>       // by using a custom filter

```
var nonCONUS = [2,15,60,66,69,72,78] // state FIPS codes that we don't want
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ZMnPbFshUI3qbk9XE0H7t1N5CjsEGyl8lZfWfVn4')
        .filter(ee.Filter.inList('STATEFP',nonCONUS).not());
print(counties, 'counties');
```

> // visualize

```
Map.addLayer(counties,{},'counties');  
var steps = 128;
```

> // get histogram precipitation values by county polygon(how to obtain custom      bin histogram,such as 64/128/256 bins)

```
var countyPrecip = annualPrecip.reduceRegions({
  collection: counties,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.autoHistogram(),
  scale: 4000 // the resolution of the GRIDMET dataset
});


print(countyPrecip);
```

> ```
> // drop .geo column (not needed if goal is tabular data)
> ```

```
var polyOut = countyPrecip.select(['.*'],null,false);
```

> ```
> // add a new column for year to each feature in the feature collection
> ```

```
polyOut = polyOut.map(function(feature){
return feature.set('Year',2017);
});
```

> ```
> // Table to Drive Export Example
> ```

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: polyOut,
  description: 'GRIDMET_annual_precip_by_county',
  folder: 'GEE_geohackweek',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the maximum number of bins for an autohistogram with the maxBuckets argument.  Unless you have fewer values than that, you should get that many buckets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, a maximum number of bins can be specified, but GEE can only return a histogram with bins less than the maximum number , however, what i want is a fixed bins histogram such as 32/64/128 . If I set the maximum number to 128, GEE maybe give me a result with 100 bins which is not equal to the expected num 128